# Can I build URLRequest with IP address in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a URLRequest like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://github.com/apple/swift")!
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.load(urlRequest)
```

If I know github.com ip address,

Can I build URLRequest with ip address?

I try change url string:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://140.82.113.3/apple/swift")!
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.load(urlRequest)
```

But, not working :(

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your info.plist and check this post by apple https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70139

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
  <dict> 
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> 
  <true/> 
  </dict>
```

It looks like you can use it, but only for test modes, not for production