# How to build Http Request with IP address in Swift?（Moya）

Tags: ios, swift, moya

Can I build Http Request with ip address?

I try change url string:

```
    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL.init(string:("http://github.com/apple/swift"))!
    }
```

to

```
    var baseURL: URL {
        return URL.init(string:("http://140.82.113.3/apple/swift"))!
    }
```

But, Network not working :(

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63571436/can-i-build-urlrequest-with-ip-address-in-swift

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var baseURL: URL = URL(string: "http://github.com/apple/swift")
```

try this ?

Comment: but I want build Http Request with ip address

Comment: just gave that as string in that place holder.. even it is IP address we supposed to make a url right ?

Comment: var baseURL: URL = URL(string: "https://173.190.43.32/abc/VC") like this

Comment: for example we don't have a domain name, how to build http request with ip address with moya

Comment: if you want to make a request you supposed to have a valid URL

Comment: var baseURL: URL = URL(string: "173.190.43.32/abc/VC")   Network not working :(

Comment: so how to create   a valid URL with ip address

Comment: have you enabled apptransportsecurity ? in the info.plist

Comment: do you have http or https as the address ?

Comment: yes ,apptransportsecurity is ture

Comment: yes ,the error message is Network connection failed

Comment: are you sure your internet is working and ip is valid ?

Comment: can you please share the error message ?

Comment: yes ,we use postman to test  this ip address,is OK. the iphone internet is working

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
  <dict> 
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> 
  <true/> 
  </dict> you added this right ?

Comment: Moya.MoyaError.underlying(Alamofire.AFError.urlRequestValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.URLRequestValidationFailureReason.bodyDataInGETRequest(23 bytes)), nil)

Comment: are you passing parameter in GET request ?

Comment: if you are trying pass params in GET please encode them using encoding: URLEncoding.default,

Comment: yes ,we try requestParameters(parameters: ["xx": xxxx], encoding: JSONEncoding.default) and  requestParameters(parameters:  ["xx": xxxx], encoding: URLEncoding.default) ,but also not work

Comment: You mean parameter errors, not special handling？

Comment: thinks ,we try other parameter,is ok.

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.